# Android using IFC files

Tags: android, 3d, ifc, bim

Can someone tell me whether it is possible to access or modify  IFC files from Android OS?

If yes, Is there any third party libraries available to view IFC files in Android.

IFC file means Industry Foundation Class is intended to describe building and construction industry data, Which is platform neutral open file format.

IFC file is exported using AutoCAD.